# Division By Zero - SUM and COUNT Statements

Tags: sql

I am getting a 'division by zero' error on my Snowflake server even during SUM and COUNT statements. The column I am summing or counting does have 0's (which is expected). The goal is to run an AVG statement to get the average tax amount.

`SELECT SUM(DutyRate) FROM preTariffDetail;` yields a 'division by zero'. As would COUNT and AVG.

I have tried wrapping the arithmetic functions in NULLIF statements, but to no avail. What would be the recourse here?

Comment: That would suggest that `preTariffDetail` is a view with a bug.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(T.DutyRate) FROM (
SELECT DutyRate FROM preTariffDetail WHERE DutyRate IS NOT NULL
) AS T
```

Comment: Checking for a NULL `DutyRate` shouldn't affect anything in OP's query.  If it does, then it's just getting around a bug in the view.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments by Gordon Linoff, it looks like `preTariffDetail` has a bug in it.

What happens if you just do a `SELECT * FROM preTariffDetail`?  I bet you'll get a division by zero error, which means the problem is in the view, not your SELECT statement.